# using swagger version 3 and bearer token in .net framework web api (not core)

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, swagger, webapi

we could not activate the latest version of swagger in .net framework 4.7.2 web api (not core). we use it as v1. how can I activate v3? also since we use jwt token, how can I activate bearer token in swagger's interface?

[my swagger config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzwqJ.png)

note: we use Swashbuckle 5.6.0

We tried everything we could find but we could not activate v3 in swagger.

How can we activate Swagger's v3 and bearer token?

thank you